# Am I using the wrong Ramda function, R.reduce doesn't appear to be working

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Given an initial message string (which in effect is acting like a format string), and contains place holders that are subsequently to be populated.

For example our initial message is:

> "GREETINGS-{year}-{mm-month}-{dd-day} - HELLO WORLD"

where there are 3 place holders, ***{year}***, ***{mm-month}***, ***{dd-day}***

and I'd like to translate this into:

> "GREETINGS-2016-06-23 - HELLO WORLD"

Given that we have an array of objects as follows:

```
[{
  "Key": "{year}",
  "Value": "2016"
}, {
  "Key": "{mm-month}",
  "Value": "06"
}, {
  "Key": "{dd-day}",
  "Value": "23"
}]
```

Each object has a Key corresponding to the place holder string inside the message, and the Value which is used to replace the place holder.

I am using the R.reduce function, since we have a collection of values (the list of objects with Key Value properties, a string replacer transformer function (tr) and the initial accumulator is the original place holder string.

The transformation function tr is defined as:

> let tr = (k, v) => { return { Key: k, Value: v } }

and the rp function which performs text replacement is defined as:

> let rp = (pair, msg) => { return R.replace(pair.Key, pair.Value, msg); }

So the desired effect is to iterate the list replacing the field name with the field value, on each iteration, return the partially poplulated string until at the end you have a fully populated string with no place holders remaining.

I modelled my solution on using R.reduce with R.add ie:

> R.reduce(R.add, 0, [1,2,3,4,5]);

which to me seems to fit the same pattern, unless I've got this wrong.

This is the invocation of R.reduce, which doesn't work as expected:

> R.reduce(rp, place_holders, pairs)

```
λ R.reduce(rp, place_holders, pairs);
TypeError: str.replace is not a function
    at replace (/Users/devuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/ramda-repl/node_modules/ramda/src/replace.js:25:14)
    at Object.f3 [as replace] (/Users/devuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/ramda-repl/node_modules/ramda/src/internal/_curry3.js:35:16)
    at XWrap.rp [as f] (repl:2:36)
    at XWrap.module.exports.XWrap.@@transducer/step (/Users/devuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/ramda-repl/node_modules/ramda/src/internal/_xwrap.js:10:17)
    at _arrayReduce (/Users/devuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/ramda-repl/node_modules/ramda/src/internal/_reduce.js:11:36)
    at _reduce (/Users/devuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/ramda-repl/node_modules/ramda/src/internal/_reduce.js:44:14)
    at Object.f3 [as reduce] (/Users/devuser/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/ramda-repl/node_modules/ramda/src/internal/_curry3.js:35:16)
λ
```

I have created a code snippet in Ramda repl at: [ramda-reply code       snippet](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20place_holders%20%3D%20"GREETINGS-%7Byear%7D-%7Bmm-month%7D-%7Bdd-day%7D%20-%20HELLO%20WORLD"%3B%0Alet%20fields%20%3D%20%5B%27%7Byear%7D%27%2C%20%27%7Bmm-month%7D%27%2C%20%27%7Bdd-day%7D%27%5D%3B%0Alet%20vals%20%3D%20%5B%272016%27%2C%20%2706%27%2C%20%2723%27%5D%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20tr%20is%20a%20function%20that%20combines%20the%20fields%20anray%20and%20the%20vals%20array%0A%2F%2F%20to%20produce%20an%20array%20of%20objects%20with%20Key%20and%20Value%20property%0A%2F%2F%0Alet%20tr%20%3D%20%28k%2C%20v%29%20%3D>%20%7B%20return%20%7B%20Key%3A%20k%2C%20Value%3A%20v%20%7D%20%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20pairs%20contains%20this%20list%20of%20objects%3A%0A%2F%2F%20%5B%7B%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20"Key"%3A%20"%7Byear%7D"%2C%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20"Value"%3A%20"2016"%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20"Key"%3A%20"%7Bmm-month%7D"%2C%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20"Value"%3A%20"06"%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20"Key"%3A%20"%7Bdd-day%7D"%2C%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20"Value"%3A%20"23"%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%5D%0A%2F%2F%0Alet%20pairs%20%3D%20R.zipWith%28tr%2C%20fields%2C%20vals%29%3B%0A%0Alet%20rp%20%3D%20%28pair%2C%20msg%29%20%3D>%20%7B%20return%20R.replace%28pair.Key%2C%20pair.Value%2C%20msg%29%3B%20%7D%0A%0Arp%28pairs%5B0%5D%2C%20place_holders%29%0A%0A%2F%2F%20-----------------%0A%2F%2F%20The%20following%20line%20...%0A%2F%2F%0A%2F%2F%20rp%28pairs%5B0%5D%2C%20place_holders%29%0A%2F%2F%0A%2F%2F%20does%20what%20is%20required%20and%20returns%20the%20string%3A%0A%2F%2F%20%0A%2F%2F%20"GREETINGS-2016-%7Bmm-month%7D-%7Bdd-day%7D%20-%20HELLO%20WORLD"%0A%2F%2F%20%28pair%5B0%5D%20equates%20to%20%7B%20"Key"%3A%20"%7Byear%7D"%2C%20"Value"%3A%20"2016"%20%7D%20%29%0A%2F%2F%0A%2F%2F%20ie%20what%20its%20doing%20is%20replacing%20field%20in%20the%20string%20with%20the%20corresponding%0A%2F%2F%20field%20value%20%28ie%20field%5B0%5D%20in%20the%20msg%20is%20replaced%20by%20vals%5B0%5D%29%0A%2F%2F%0A%2F%2F%20Now%20I%20would%20like%20to%20use%20the%20reduce%20function%20so%20that%20we%20can%20iterate%20over%20all%20of%0A%2F%2F%20objects%20in%20the%20pair%20collection%20so%20that%20at%20the%20end%20the%20final%20message%20returned%0A%2F%2F%20does%20not%20contain%20the%20field%20names%3B%20they%20have%20all%20been%20replaced%20by%20corresponding%20field%0A%2F%2F%20values%2C%20ie%3A%0A%2F%2F%0A%2F%2F%20"GREETINGS-2016-06-23%20-%20HELLO%20WORLD"%0A%2F%2F%20-----------------%0A%2F%2F%0A%2F%2F%20So%20using%20the%20reduce%20function%2C%0A%2F%2F%20-%20the%20collection%20to%20be%20iterated%20over%20is%20%27pairs%27%0A%2F%2F%20-%20the%20initial%20accumulator%20is%20place_holders%20string%20containing%20the%20field%20names%0A%2F%2F%0A%2F%2F%20But%20invocation%20of%20%27R.reduce%28rp%2C%20place_holders%2C%20pairs%29%27%20results%20in%20an%20error%20message%0A%2F%2F%20%27r.replace%20is%20not%20a%20function%27%0AR.reduce%28rp%2C%20place_holders%2C%20pairs%29%0A%0A%2F%2F%20So%20either%20I%27m%20invoking%20reduce%20incorrectly%20or%20R.reduce%20is%20the%20wrong%20function%20for%20this%0A%2F%2F%20requirement.%0A%2F%2F%0A%0A%0A%0A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close, you just transposed the two arguments in your reducer function. Instead of this:

```
let rp = (pair, msg) => { return R.replace(pair.Key, pair.Value, msg); }
```

do this:

```
let rp = (msg, pair) => { return R.replace(pair.Key, pair.Value, msg); }
```

```js
const place_holders = "GREETINGS-{year}-{mm-month}-{dd-day} - HELLO WORLD";
let fields = ['{year}', '{mm-month}', '{dd-day}'];
let vals = ['2016', '06', '23'];

let tr = (k, v) => { return { Key: k, Value: v } }

let pairs = R.zipWith(tr, fields, vals);

let rp = (msg, pair) => { return R.replace(pair.Key, pair.Value, msg);}

console.log(R.reduce(rp, place_holders, pairs))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Argh wow, thanks for that. How do I avoid making that type of error in the future? There must be a relationship between how R.reduce is passing arguments to the function, but I can't see this

Comment: This is the same order that the native `reduce` passes arguments to its callback: accumulator first, then current value.  (The native one also passes additional arguments that Ramda chooses not to supply.)

Comment: The first value passed to the reducer is the accumulator. Ie, the value you're building up. The second value is the current element of the array that we're incoporating into the accumulator. The ramda docs mention this, and it's also the same order that Array.reduce uses (though array.reduce also passes in some extra params) https://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduce

Comment: Note that in your functions, `(foo) => {return expression}` can be more simply written as `(foo) => expression`.  This only works if there is a single expression in the brackets, but it's a nice clean-up.

Answer (score 3):

As Nicholas Tower pointed out, this error was a simple transposition.  My version would be to wrap that imperative code inside a function, so I might write something like this:

```js
const fillIn = (fields, place_holders, vals) => reduce(
  (str, {Key, Val}) => replace(Key, Val, str), 
  place_holders, 
  zipWith((Key, Val) => ({Key, Val}), fields, vals)
)

const place_holders = "GREETINGS-{year}-{mm-month}-{dd-day} - HELLO WORLD";
let fields = ['{year}', '{mm-month}', '{dd-day}'];
let vals = ['2016', '06', '23'];

console.log(fillIn(fields, place_holders, vals))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>
const {reduce, replace, zipWith} = R
</script>
```

I might also wrap that in `curry`, if I wanted to partially apply the fields (and maybe the placeholder.)

---

**Update**: you might also want to consider a different data structure.  Using two arrays to store paired values based on shared indices is often brittle.  This structure holds the same information in a more robust manner:

```
{year: '2016', 'mm-month': '06', 'dd-day': '23'}
```

Using this also lets you work with placeholders more dynamically, using a regular expression:

```js
const fillIn = (placeHolder, context) => placeHolder.replace(
  /\{([^}]+)\}/g, 
  (s, key) => key in context ? context[key] : `{${key}}`
)

const context = {year: '2016', 'mm-month': '06', 'dd-day': '23'}

console.log(fillIn("GREETINGS-{year}-{mm-month}-{dd-day} - HELLO WORLD", context))
console.log(fillIn("GREETINGS-{foobar}-{mm-month}-{dd-day} - HELLO WORLD", context))
```

There is a down-side to this.  This will fail if you have nested curly braces in your string.  I would actually use templates more like the built-in string template ones, `"GREETINGS-${year}-${mm-month}-${dd-day} - HELLO WORLD"` in order to avoid this problem, and to make them stand out better.  That extra `$` would have to be added to the regex as well, but this is easy: `/\$\{([^}]+)\}/g`.

This technique may be of no help to you.  If those data structures are coming from an external system, then you're stuck.  But if you're in control of them, consider this a possibly more flexible and more robust version of what you've already got.

Comment: Thats great Scott, I'll take that on board too